# want to add a second dice and get random result diffrent than the first

Tags: kotlin, random

Hi everybody I'm trying to practice a little bit further than what I've been asked to do.

Good ol dice roller one activity android app.

I successfully added another imageView but when rolling I'd like to show different result.

What's the best practice ?

Here's what I code for the first dice:

```
    private fun rollDice() {
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()
        
        val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        val drawableResource = when (diceRoll) {
            1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
            2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
            3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
            4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
            else -> R.drawable.dice_5

        }
        // mets a jour l image du dé correspondant
        diceImage.setImageResource(drawableResource)

    }

}
```

Then I simply coded a fun `rollDice2` with `imageView2`...

This is working fine but I guess there is a more consised way to do it.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd break this into two functions to avoid repetition.

```
fun rollBothDice() {
    val dice = Dice(6)
    setDiceImage(findViewById(R.id.imageView), dice.roll())
    setDiceImage(findViewById(R.id.imageView2), dice.roll())
}

private fun setDiceImage(imageView: ImageView, value: Int) {
    val drawableResource = when (value) {
        1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
        2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
        3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
        4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
        else -> R.drawable.dice_5
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(drawableResource)
}
```

If all the Dice class does is provide a way to pick a random number, it's probably easier to just use a range:

```
fun rollBothDice() {
    val values = 1..6
    setDiceImage(findViewById(R.id.imageView), values.random())
    setDiceImage(findViewById(R.id.imageView2), values.random())
}
```

Comment: Sorry i think i should have say getting random result for both just like when you throw two dices.

Comment: Oh, you said "different result". I'll edit the answer.